# ctypes python unpacking three dimensional array (3x3x48) array, matrix?

Tags: multidimensional-array, ctypes

Using ctypes, I can't seem to access the third dimension correctly in a 3-dim array(3x3x48)

To test things, I created a ctypes array:

```
opsOUT =(((c_double * 3) *3)*48)()
```

In my real application, a Fortran routine returns the array full of data.  But for now I'm trying to debug things by simply printing out these zeros in python and assigning them to a python array:

```
def unload_ctypes_3x3x48_double(OUT):
"""Take a ctypes array and load it into a python array"""
a = zeros((3,3,48),dtype=np_float)
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        for k in range(48):
           print [i,j,k], OUT[i][j][k]                
           a[i,j,k] = OUT[i][j][k]
return a
```

But

```
unload_ctypes_3x3x48_double(opsOUT)
```

gives

```
[0, 0, 0] 0.0
[0, 0, 1] 0.0
[0, 0, 2] 0.0
[0, 0, 3]
IndexError: invalid index
```

So k goes only to 2, and when it reaches 3 it gives the error, but it should go to 47

Any ideas of how to fix this?

Comment: A Fortran array is laid out in column-major order. But a ctypes array (as in C types, not Fortran types) is laid out in row-major order. In memory it's like `[[[X,X,X,], [X,X,X], [X,X,X]], ...]` for 48 rows. The first index goes from 0 to 47.

Answer (score 0):

To reference with the indices you want, declare them in reverse order:

```
>>> opsOUT = (((c_double*48)*3)*3)()
>>> opsOUT[2][2][47]
0.0
```

But note @eryksun's comment that Fortran lays out arrays in memory differently.

Comment: A NumPy array can use Fortran ('F') order, e.g. `arr = np.array([[0.0,1],[2,3]], order='F'); assert arr.strides == (8, 16); assert cast(arr.ctypes, POINTER(c_double * 4))[0][:] == [0.0, 2.0, 1.0, 3.0]`. This abstracts some away some of the ABI difference, but there are still quirks with exported symbol names and hidden parameters in calls. I think you'll be happier using [F2py](http://wiki.scipy.org/F2py) to create an extension module instead of using ctypes.